# Deduce modulus N from public exponent and encrypted data

Tags: encryption, cryptography, certificate, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

This is an RSA question, given data encrypted with a public key from an unknown RSA certificate of 2048 bit, let X be the encrypted data, M the unencrypted data, c the public exponent and N it's modulus. Knowing X, M and c, can you deduce N?

```
X = M^c mod N
```

You can have as many M and corresponding X as you want, hence:

```
X1 = M1^c mod N

X2 = M2^c mod N
```

...

I want to know if this is possible, mathematically and programatically. A brute force won't work here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: subtraction, and GCD.

Comment: M^c = q*N + X -> N = (M^c - X) / q -> find q so that (M^c - X) % q == 0 ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) instead of programming (check if the question exists before asking or migrating there).

Comment: @NicolasVidela: Yes, so you know M^c - X is *divisible* by N. But M^c - X is *huge*, too big to factor. However, what if you have two such values? You have both M1^c - X1 and M2^c - X2 both divisible by N.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.